# CORS request using jQuery - $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, cors

I am developing a web application where data is coming from different domain. I mean in my application almost 90% request are cross domain request.

I am unable to get the data while deploy this application on IIS.

Server is deployed on http://some.ip.add/crmservice
client is deployed on http://diffent.ip.add/saascrm

I am using jQuery 2.0 to get the data in async manner using $.ajax();

Note: **data is coming in xml format**

Added some stuff to web.config file also.

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

This is my snippet.

```
$.support.cors = true;
      $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: 'http://some.ip.add/crmservice/crmservice.asmx/HandShake', 
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        beforeSend: function (request) {
                        //    debugger;
                            request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            try {
                              //  debugger;
                                // debugger;
                              //Here i am getting error : Access denied in IE 9.0 and and just "error" in firefox. 
                                var msg = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                                alert(msg.Message);
                            }
                            catch (e) {
                                // debugger;
                                alert(xhr.statusText);
                            }
                            return true;

                        },
                        success: function (data) {
                            debugger;
                            xmlDoc1 = $.parseXML(data.d);
                            $xml1 = $(xmlDoc1);
                            if ($xml1.find('Result').text() == '0') {
                                $(this).MessageBox('success', $xml1.find('Message').text());
                                $("#uxDBName").prop("disabled", false);
                                $("#uxSUPassword").prop("disabled", false);
                                $("#uxServiceURL").prop("disabled", true);
                                GetListOfB1Databases(url);
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

my server code is :

Global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall();  
    }
    private void EnableCrossDmainAjaxCall()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Content-Type, Accept");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "1728000");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }

     //Web method
     [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json), WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public string HandShake()
    {
        return General.Response("0", "Tenant is in reachable. Please specify SAP Business One Company database\r\nand 'manager' Password", "");
    }
```

I found some solutions on [this](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2010/03/12/making-cross-domain-javascript-requests-using-xmlhttprequest-or-xdomainrequest.html) also, I found that CORS is not supported by IE 8 & 9.
IE 8 * 9 does not create the instance of XMLHttpRequest object. It create XDomainRequest, so need to check for the user agent. I found an alternate solution [here](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/2010/03/12/making-cross-domain-javascript-requests-using-xmlhttprequest-or-xdomainrequest.html)

Now my problem is I have use $.ajax() method everywhere almost 90% call is cross domain call. I don't want to make this major change in my framework.

Is there any solution to this using $.ajax()?

Please help me, I am badly stuck since a week.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UM, JSON !== XML You said you are returning XML, but your Ajax code is showing that you are expecting JSON.

Comment: So there is a jQuery plugin that does the XDomainRequest with the jQuery ajax. https://github.com/MoonScript/jQuery-ajaxTransport-XDomainRequest

Comment: and i don't think xml is accessible cross domain. AFAIK `jsonp` is required for accessing the cross domain data and data should be in `json` format.

Comment: @Jai, with CORS it does not matter.

Comment: @epascarello actually i never been to this situation before and i never look around for it with xml. Thanks though will look for it now.

Comment: If you are using jQuery 2.0, um, how are you [supporting IE8](http://jquery.com/browser-support/)?

Comment: @epascarello, I am using IE 9 and not IE8, I just mention here what I read. I can set it to xml, but right now it's json and the point is it is working on my local machine have json datatype.

Comment: @Jai: I don't think it matter either json or xml, ultimately its just data which required to be transport over the network across domains.

Comment: @Manish, datatype/mimetype is matter for CORS, sometime server is configured to type of request (PUT/POST/DELETE/..)  and content-type should be pass over cross domain requests.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your cooperation and help that you provide me.
I found solution.

```js
 var url = $("#uxServiceURL").val();
        $.ajax({
            crossOrigin: true,
            url: url + '/HandShake',
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                try {
                    alert('Error');
                }
                catch (e) {
                    alert(xhr.statusText);
                }
                return true;
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var d1 = data.replace(/\&lt;/g, '<').replace(/\&gt;/g, '>')
                xmlDoc1 = $.parseXML(d1);

                $xml1 = $(xmlDoc1);
                if ($xml1.find('Result').text() == '0') {
                    $(this).MessageBox('success', $xml1.find('Message').text());
                   
                }
            }
        });
```